# How to create a text box in PHP to output data

Tags: php, html, css, textbox

I am fairly new to PHP and HTML, and I was wondering what kind of css statements is required to generate text box to output a value in one of my PHP functions.

Currently the function looks looks up data from a SQL server and returns it; however, what I wanted to do is display that data in text box just to confirm that it is grabbing the correct value.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you're asking.  PHP has nothing to do with CSS or HTML directly.  It just runs server-side and outputs whatever you tell it to output.  The CSS and HTML are interpreted client-side in the browser.  "How to create a text box in PHP using CSS" is nonsensical.

Comment: PHP runs on the server side and sends HTML to the client. So the question should be: How can I display a textbox in HTML

Comment: My bad. I guess I would have to use HTML in my PHP file  in order to check the output being grabbed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$var = 'your value';
echo '<input type="text" name="name1" value="'.$var.'">';
```

If you want textarea

```
echo '<textarea class="box">'.$var.'</textarea>';
```

But CSS is used for designing. It depends on yourself how you want to design it. An example for designing the textarea by box class

```
<style>
    .box{
        border: 1px solid #aaa; /*getting border*/
        border-radius: 4px; /*rounded border*/
        color: #000; /*text color*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: JUst what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an actual textbox? This is what I use to display php messages.

```
.messagebox {
position:fixed;
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
border:3px solid #ffffff;
font-family:'Voltaire', sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
width:180px;
border-radius:15px;
z-index:1;
padding:10px;
}

<div class="messagebox">
<?php echo $message ?>
</div>
```

$message being the variable to echo.